# Apache not able to access document root when outside the network

Tags: apache, debian

I have a wordpress site on my debian server. I have done the port forwarding successfully (verified this) to access outside the network. However I get the below error when i try to access outside the network. Am i missing something? Sites-available is set to documentroot at /var/www, which is where my wordpress folder is.

---

The requested URL /XXXXXX was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at 10.1.1.4 Port 80

---

I really hope someone can help me on this as i have spent almost a week over this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of stuff on daily basis. Lets go through the basics.

Firstly, confirm that you can access your server within your private network  http://yourserverLANip:80
If possible, do not use server itself to test it (eg localhost:80), use other device as laptop or any other device within the same LAN.

With that test you can confirm that:

- apache listens on port 80
- apache accepts requests from other clients within your private network
- wordpress is set up correctly

If wordpress site pops up we can assume that apache and private network configuration is correct and you'd need to move your debugging to WAN/public network configuration.

It would be wise to recheck apache security settings at this point.

From here, things get a little more complicated.
I believe you mean public WWW when you say "outside-the-network". You want to make your site public to every internet user on the planet.

I assume that you have a registered domain name (eg yourwebsitename.com) and a static public IP address at the location where the server is located (if you host it at home, static IP is fixed to your modem).
These two are "must", if you want to host anything that public can consume. 
If you host your apache for yourself, you dont need your domain name, but you'd need to access your server through your public IP yourpublicIP:80 and it's not easy to use for other people.

Now lets go on with WAN debugging.

Validate that:

- your domain DNS WWW settings are pointing to your public IP address
  at your server location. you can do it through the control panel of
  your domain registrant company.
- you have a static public IP address where your server is hosted
- your modem accepts incoming ports (80). this is done through modem
  firewall settings.
- that the port 80 is redirected to your server private IP address (LAN
  ip).

The flow for redirecting clients to your server is something like that:

Client->WWW->internet service provider->yourpublicIP->modem->yourserver at LAN

Good hunting!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.
Within the network, when I do xx.xx.xx.xx:80 I get pointed to a previously set (not by me) xx.xx.xx.xx:8181/portal

How do i disable this?

My wordpress files are at /var/www/wordpress

Comment: I changed the settings & ports at /etc/apache2 several times but to no avail. Currently the default file at /etc/apache2/sites-available is as below:

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName devclc
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#               AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

Comment: If i understand the situation correctly then 8181 setting is set by your wordpress installation.

Comment: If i understand the situation correctly then 8181 setting is set by your wordpress installation. See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/alternate-port-setup to confirm it. Did you set up your wp as standalone or did you use somekind of installer? If it is bundeled installation then it may have some kind other webserver in front of it, eg ngnix, that handles port 8181. Id reccomend standalone wp, just unzip it to /var/www as documentation suggests.  You can find out what services listens on ports usinghttp://serverfault.com/questions/357323/how-can-i-list-my-open-ports-on-debian

Comment: The wp is standalone, which i backup from an older server using the duplicator plugin, and installed it into this current server. I am actually very skeptical of meddling with the url settings at the wp dashboard because at 2 different occasions I have been locked out of the dashboard after changing the url.